# Android apk: NoClassDefFoundError on class that are part of dependencies

Tags: java, android, apk

Observe that my [build.grade](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/blob/master/app/build.gradle) includes  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.2' . Yet, Android 4.4 [users report](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/issues/2) that the app crashes with the error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream .

Why is it the case? I observe that the signed apk I produce using Android Studio does not have the above class (why??), yet the apk works fine with Android 5.0 and on an emulated Android 4.x.

Questions:

- What's going on here?
- How can I force the apk to contain within it classes from the dependencies?

Comment: Try to get compress jar and add into libs folder and also remove this line :  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.2' from build.gradle.

Comment: Tried it - doesn't work.